# I keep getting type mismatch when i run my code

Tags: vba, excel

When I run my code, I keep getting a type mismatch error even though all the variables are defined as variants. I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm kind of new to VBA so I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

```
Sub drink_2()
Columns("E:H").Insert shift:=xlToRight, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("F6").value = "Drink Price"
Range("G6").value = "Drink Revenue"
Range("H6").value = "Gross Sales less Drink Revenue"
Dim i As Variant
Dim item As Variant
Dim drink_price As Variant
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\username\Documents\vlookup table drink prices.xlsx")
Dim lookup_range As Variant
lookup_range = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B").value
i = 7
Do While Cells(i, 1).value <> ""
item = Cells(i, 1).value
Cells(11, 1).value = item
drink_price = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, lookup_range, 2, False)
zero_check = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(drink_price, 0)
If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, lookup_range, 2, False)) Then
    Cells(i, 6).value = ""
Else
    Cells(i, 6).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, lookup_range, 2, False)
End If
Cells(i, 7).Formula = Cells(i, 6).value * Cells(i, 5).value
Cells(i, 8).Formula = Cells(i, 4).value - Cells(i, 7).value
Range("F:G").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
i = i + 1
Loop
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: One which line of code does the error occur ***??***

Comment: On which line you get that error? Please provide as much information as possible.

Comment: The VLOOKUP will not pass the error to the variable with `.WorksheetFunction` it will stop the code.  You need to remove that part from your vlookups.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the problem line:

`lookup_range = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B").value`

You should be getting a range, not a value, so you need to use the set keyword and drop the value property.

`set lookup_range = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B")`